# Trying to mVBA code for filling up cells with values and formatake a

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to make a code to transform table 1 to table 2 (see image).

[image]

First table (small one) represents input values : width and length of rectangles to create (numbers 2,7,43 and 4,12,4) and values and formatting to be filled (letters will be inputted numerical values)
Second table to be created by code (numbers on the outline are not so important)

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: As this is mainly reading and writing cells and use some loops, this is rather easy. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.